# Incluir contenido de span en envío AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Tengo el siguiente código el cual son datos que obtengo de varios `input` y `select` los cuales los envio por AJAX. También quiero enviar un dato que obtengo en una etiqueta `span`.

```
function enviarCotizacion() {
$('#form').on("submit",function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault(); //evita que la pagina se  autorecargue 
    var cotizacion=$(this).serialize();
    var span=$('#form').find('#monto_euro'); 
    var precio_euro=span.text();
    console.log(precio_euro);

   $.ajax({
    "method": "POST",
    "url": "php/server.php",
    "data": cotizacion
   }).done(function (response){ //respuesta [response] del servidor
    $('#info').append('<span>'+response+'</span>');
   });   
});
```

Mi problema es al enviar el dato del `<span>`; creo entender que no puedo enviar valores de etiquetas como `span`, las cuales no son enviadas por AJAX.

¿Algún consejo para enviar ese valor del `span` junto con otros valores los cuales les doy `serialize()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Por que no ibas a poder enviar contenido de etiquetas span?, es una etiqueta como otra cualquiera. Ahora bien, para poder introducirlo, lo más sencillo es que lo trabajes como un array, en vez de `serialize();` usa `serializeArray();`.

```
    function enviarCotizacion(){
        $('#form').on("submit", function(ev){
            ev.preventDefault(); //evita que la pagina se  autorecargue 
            var cotizacion = $(this).serializeArray();
            var precio_euro = $('#monto_euro').html();
            cotizacion.push({ name: "precio_euro", value: precio_euro});

            $.ajax({
                "method": "POST",
                "url": "php/server.php",
                "data": cotizacion
            }).done(function (response) { //respuesta [response] del servidor
                $('#info').append('<span>' + response + '</span>');
            });
        });
    }
```

Además, tampoco tiene sentido si el span tiene una ID buscarlo dentro de otra ID, puedes recoger directamente su valor mediante `var precio_euro = $('#monto_euro').html();`.

Prueba y nos comentas, saludos

Comment: Solucionado y dudas despejadas Gracias.

Comment: Hola @Danserver, me alegra poder haberte sido de ayuda. Para ayudar a otros miembros de la comunidad, puedes marcar la pregunta como solucionada marcando mi respuesta como "Aceptada".